# Python 2.7 tkinter messagebox.askquestion stopped working

Tags: python, tkinter

I was writing some code, and it stopped worked out of the blue. I reverted all the code back, and it still doesn't work.

I now get the error " AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox' "

Here are my original includes

```
from __future__ import print_function
import Tkinter as tki
import ttk
import ScrolledText as tkst
import time
from array import array
import os
from Tkinter import *
import sys
```

I did some searching and added these, but it still doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkMessageBox import *
```

Here's the code that accesses it.

```
MsgBox = tki.messagebox.askquestion
```

I have no clue why it just stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you imported messagebox from tkinter, why don't you try removing tki from the piece of code

```
  MsgBox=tki.messagebox.askquestion()
```

Then maybe, the program will not show any error. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yup, that was it... Thank you! The original code worked for a month, then just broke.

Comment: This won't open the dialog. It makes the same mistake as the OP: it's missing `()`.

Comment: Now there are brackets. I'm sure it will work now, provided there are proper arguments.

Comment: @BryanOakley Opps. There were (), but they had data in them. I assume I didn't copy them on purpose, then forget to add them back in.